# ajax:getting images as response to a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

so i have a basic php page with links and when the user click on the "gallery" link i want the main div in which i am displaying the content to load a grid of images.

this is the sample code of what i am doing:

```
myreq = new XMLHttpRequest();

myreq.open("GET","my gallery.php",true);
myreq.send(null);
myreq.onreadystatechange = function(){


if (myreq.readyState == 4)
{       
    $("#maindiv").html(myreq.responseText);
}
}
```

I am getting the gallery file in the `div` alright but I am getting it with tags instead of getting the image itself.

I am getting:

```
img src=url alt=text etc
```

In short I am getting the text in the file.

Comment: post your mygallery.php file code here

Comment: Why are you not using `$.ajax` or `$.get` since you are using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this in two ways:

1. Modify your PHP Code in such a way, it returns this:

   ```
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image" />
   ```

   And use this code:

   ```
   $("#mainDiv").load("my gallery.php");
   ```
2. Else, you can do this way. Modify your PHP Code in such a way, it returns an image and change the JavaScript this way:

   ```
   $("#mainDiv").html('<img src="my gallery.php" alt="Image" />');
   ```

*ps: As said by everyone, if you are using jQuery, use jQuery's `$.ajax` or its functions, instead of using XHR!*

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using jQuery, you should try this instead of all your code :

```
$( "#mainDiv" ).load("my gallery.php");
```

This will result by putting all HTML in remote file into the #mainDiv element.